# How do I get Steam games on the Windows 7 Game Explorer?

Tags: steam, windows-7

How do I get Steam games on the Windows 7 Game Explorer?  I have a few games installed in Steam that I'd like to appear in the Game Explorer.

Yes, I know I can create a desktop shortcut and drag that over. But they just don't look right compared to other games that install themselves "properly" to the Game Explorer, and I'd like to keep it looking tidy.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The only way for a game to appear in the Game Explorer, other than dragging over a shortcut, is for the game to register itself as a game with Windows. Since this is dependent on the game, if no entry is made by the game itself, there is no alternative to the shortcut method.

Comment: thanks, I thought that would be the answer, but it's been bothered me for *ages* and thought it's always worth checking, just in case.

Comment: I know that the Steam version of Borderlands does automatically put a link into the Games Explorer. I'll check and see if any others I have do.

Comment: My Steam version of Red Faction made an icon as well. I imagine other Games For Windows would too, like Fallout 3.

Comment: Yes, I just checked. Aliens vs Predator does, Battlefield Bad Company 2 does and Defcon too.

Answer (score 3):

Games that bear the "Games for Windows" logo do this automatically, and some games too, if you installed them from a medium (CD/DVD) and not downloaded it from Steam.

Other than that, I have never seen a game I downloaded from Steam register itself in the Game Explorer.

Answer (score 3):

Some games in Steam have an "Add to Game Explorer" option in the Steam Library right-click menu. But it depends on the game.